# increment value in blender

Tags: python, scripting

I am new to python and blender and I need to increment a variable value in blender but I can't! When I run this code, my cube is translated but I can't add another translation, so I can't increment a value of my variable bpy.context.object.location[0].

```
import bpy

bpy.context.object.location[0] = 1

if bpy.context.object.location[0] > 0:
    # I corrected the formatting
    # and assumed the indentation is correct - MvB
    bpy.context.object.location[0] += 1

print(bpy.context.object.location[0])
```

Comment: Are you sure you can't increment the value? Try doing it without a conditional statement - perhaps the problem is not about incrementing but about the conditional statement, or the object of interest not being active. I tested your code and got `2.0` as output, as I expected (first set to `1` then add `1`). Also, when you paste code, select it and press codeblock button to make sure it's shown properly https://i.imgur.com/XGtH11e.png

Comment: Every time you run your script you begin by assigning the value of 1 to your objects location. As such it will increment from 1 to 2 then when you re-run your script it assigns the value 1 to the x location again and increments by 1 again. remove the `bpy.context.object.location[0] = 1` from your script to be able to add one each time you run the script.